# What is this VBScript Function Doing

Tags: c#, vbscript

I have a function in VBScript, what is it doing? how can I simplify it using C# 2.0.

```
Function FormatString(format, args)
    Dim RegExp, result

    result = format

    Set RegExp = New RegExp 

    With RegExp
        .Pattern = "\{(\d{1,2})\}"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = RegExp.Execute(result)

    For Each match In matches   
        dim index
        index = CInt(Mid(match.Value, 2, Len(match.Value) - 2))
        result = Replace(result, match.Value, args(index))
    Next
    Set matches = nothing
    Set RegExp = nothing

    FormatString = result
End Function
```

thanks!

Comment: Looks like VB.NET to me, not VBScript - to very different animals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the code to C#

```
static string FormatString(string format, string[] args)
{
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex RegExp;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection matches;
    string result;

    result = format;

    RegExp = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\{(\d{1,2})\}", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    matches = RegExp.Matches(result);

    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches)
    {
        int index;

        index = Convert.ToInt32(match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 1));
        result = result.Replace(match.Value, args[index]);
    }

    matches = null;
    RegExp = null;

    return result;
}
```

please let me know of any issues

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a simplified version of the .NET [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method.

It takes a format string with curly-brace delimited placeholders (e.g. `"{0} {1}"`), and substitutes each one in turn with a corresponding value from the `args` array.  You might be able to swap it out for `String.Format` without any change in functionality.

Comment: This has nothing to do with string.format.  It's using regex pattern matching.

Comment: @BradleyUffner it's using regex pattern matching to implement a very simplified version of string.format

Answer (score 1):

It's searching a string for everything that matches the specified regex pattern and replacing it with some other string from a list of those passed in to the function.

Based on my (limited) skills with regex, it seems to be looking for 1 or 2 digit numbers in the input string, and replacing them with the value in an array that is passed in to the function.

Here is some documentation from MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

It could be replaced with String.Format as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

And example from the linked page on usage.

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17, 9, 30, 0); 
string city = "Chicago";
int temp = -16;
string output = String.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.",
                              dat, city, temp);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output:
//    At 1/17/2012 9:30:00 AM in Chicago, the temperature was -16 degrees.
```